How to convert bytes into Excel file in Python?
I opened an Excel file using open method in Python:
open('word.docx','rb') as excel: hit=excel.read().

Now after adding some text to it, I would like to convert or write the bytes back to an Excel file. How can I do that? I tried using the write method but an error appears saying the file is corrupted.

Have you looked into the existing libraries for handling Excel files? You've got a lot of work to do if you just treat it as a stream of bytes.

As a matter of fact it is not just excel file. i wish to convert the most basic ones(pdf,word,excel,txt) into bytes, modify them and then convert them back. is there a library to handle each type of file or a specific library is needed for each of them?

You cannot write Excel, Word, PDF etc files like that, they are all structured differently. You need to use one of the specific libraries that handle thos file types: pydoc — Documentation generator and online help system, pyexcel - Let you focus on data, instead of file formats, etc.
